# How to do a feature test in Rails with Capybara and how to know 500 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

I created a route in my Rails application as:

```
scope 'product' do
  get '/', to: 'product#sort', as: 'product'
end
```

Then I want to test my feature with Capybara as:

```
# spec/features/product_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Product', type: :feature do
  describe 'Main page' do
    context 'Before login' do
      it 'Show product list' do
        visit product_path
        expect(page).to have_content('Product List')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But after I run rspec in the terminal, it showed me:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Product List')
  expected to find text "Product List" in "500 Internal Server Error"
```

Why it gave me a 500 error? What happened? How can I see the error detail?

In my controller and view, I set `@product_categories`:

In controller:

```
# app/controllers/product_controller.rb
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def sort
    @product_categories = ProductCategory.all
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

In view:

```
# app/views/product/sort.html.erb
<h1>Product List</h1>

<% @product_categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
<% end %>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

Is it necessary to define that value in the spec test source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling a `.each` on a class. I think you mean

```
@product_categories = ProductCategories.all
```

in your controller. Also, by convention, your controllers and view folder name should be pluralized, so `products_controller.rb` with class name `ProductsController` and views folder look like `app/views/products/sort.html.erb`. In your route, also pluralize the controller like so `'products#sort'`.

As for your test, it seems like you are using a mix of rspec and capybara DSL. If you use feature, you don't need `:type => :feature`. You need to combine the `description`, `context`, and `it` into `scenario`. Refer here for an example in the Using capybara with Rspec built in DSL section: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed that. Now I don't know why it showed me 500 error, I can see a good result in the web browser.

Comment: forgot to mention, change in the route to 'products#sort' also

Comment: I really don't know why and how to see the 500 problem for a detail.

Comment: that means when you visit product_path, its not working. Get rid of the scope and use get '/scope', to: 'products#sort', as: 'product'